# Slicing a set of columns when a pandas dataframe does not include column labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to slice the **last** `n` columns from pandas dataframe assuming the dataframe does not include column labels? For instance, I want to slice the last 4 columns:

```
data = np.random.uniform(0,10,(4,10)).astype(np.int)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.ix[:,4])
```

Can someone fix this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `iloc` instead of `ix` with `-4:` columns:

```
print(df.iloc[:,-4:])
```